# renderInput error while using <DatePicker> from MUI X

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

I am using the below for <DatePicker>. Saw a lot of videos and sandbox where it works fine.

Not sure why I am getting the below error on renderInput

```
<DatePicker
        label="Basic example"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={(newValue) => { setSelectedDate(newValue) }}
        renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
      />
```

```
Type '{ label: string; value: Date; onChange: (newValue: Date) => void; renderInput: (props: any) => Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DatePickerProps<Date> & RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.
  Property 'renderInput' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DatePickerProps<Date> & RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of MUI X are you using?

I don't see the `renderInput` prop listed on the `<DatePicker>` API:
https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/

It looks like in the most recent version, the `slots` prop should be used to customize the internal HTML components: https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#slots

See here for more information: https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/custom-components/#overriding-components

Specifically, the `TextField` component might be the one you're looking to target.

Note that there is also a `slotProps` prop:

```
<DatePicker
  {...otherProps}
  slots={{
    // Override default <ActionBar /> with a custom one
    actionBar: CustomActionBar,
  }}
  slotProps={{
    // pass props `actions={['clear']}` to the actionBar slot
    actionBar: { actions: ['clear'] },
  }}
/>
```

If this doesn't get you where you're heading, can you share the sandbox that shows the working example you've referenced, in addition to your MUI version?

Answer (score 3):

`renderInput` is the prop used in **@mui/x-date-pickers v5** and since **v6** were launched it's replaced with customization through slots.
So, equivalent to `renderInput` in a new version is:

```
<DatePicker
  {...props}
  slots={{
    textField: textFieldProps => <CustomTextField {...textFieldProps} />
  }}
/>
```